# Express not serving NPM installed Bootstrap JS, but is reachable via direct link

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, bootstrap-5

I have installed Bootstrap 5 and Express via NPM. In my Express app, I am statically including the bootstrap files with:

```js
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/')))
```

In my `index.ejs`, file, I have the following head:

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive" />
    <title>My Website Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script defer language="javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
```

The css loads with no issues at all. The javascript never loads.

What is bizarre is that going to `http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js` immediately serves up the file in 14ms. Same for `http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`. So I know Express will serve the javascript.

Examining the network tab shows a status of `pending` for the js file. Changing the source to something like `<script defer language="javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.nonexistant.js"></script>` immediately returns status `404`.

Why is it not loading when I try to access it via the webpage?

Comment: Try setting the header `Content-Type: text/javascript` when serving your JS files. Are you getting any errors in the JS console? Also, change your language="javascript" to type="text/javascript" because language="javascript" is considered obsolete. Also, you are specifying `bootstrap.bundle.js`, but saying `bootstrap.min.js` loads. Double-check that, I assume you just made a typo in the question.

Comment: Loading `bootstrap.bundle.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` both work when accessed by `http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js` and `http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js` respectively. Ideally, I am after `min`. But neither one is working when loaded from the html side.

Comment: @LeonardoG changing it to `<script defer language="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` causes it to not even load the javascript at all.

Comment: Also strangely, if I hit refresh over and over occasionally it will come up with a status 200 for the javascript and it works. That is even stranger...

Comment: It's `type="text/javascript"`, not `language="text/javascript"`, you can remove the language attribute entirely. If that doesn't work, it seems like an issue with the web server considering it sometimes loads, and sometimes doesn't. Is your server able to serve both requests at the same time (css + js)?

Comment: I changed the `langauage` to `type`. It still only loads intermittently. I keep having to refresh over and over until the resource loads. I'm doing local dev using nodemon to serve the Express app. Does that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but we haven't seen your Express code, so can't know for sure. Can you go to your browser, access the javascript file directly through the browser and make sure to tick 'disable cache' in your Chrome dev tools in the network tab, and then try to refresh the JS file a few times? Does it load properly every time when it doesn't use cache?

Comment: One more thing to try: remove the trailing slash in your static path. `app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist')))`